# How use OpenCV Imgproc.HoughLines in java?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to find hough lines in an image using opencv in java.

This is my code :

```
public static final double RHO = 2;
public static final double THETA = 3 * Math.PI;
public static final int THRESHOLD = 100;
.
.
.
Mat lines = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughLines(inputRgba, lines, RHO, THETA, THRESHOLD);
```

but I have an error :

```
 error: (-215) img.type() == CV_8UC1 in function void cv::HoughLinesStandard(const cv::Mat&, float, float, int, std::vector<cv::Vec<float, 2> >&, int, double, double)
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: your `inputRgba` needs to be a grayscale image, the error is telling you it expects an 8-bit single channel image which means grayscale

Comment: You should check this  link https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc&method=HoughLinesP